# Multiple Tags should apply one [hover]CSS of Parent

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
       HTML CODE

        <ul id="info">
            <li>
                <h3><span>Text1</span>Text2
                    <img src="path" alt="" />
                </h3>
                <p> DATA1 </p>
                <p class="descrip"> DATA2 </p>
            </li>
        </ul>

      CSS CODE

       ul#info {width:100%;float:left}
       ul#info li {width:226px;margin-left:56px;float:left}
       ul#info li:first-child {margin:0}
       ul#info li h3 {width:100%;height:67px;float:left;font-size:26px;color:#31a1ff;font-weight:bold;line-height:60px;letter-spacing:-1.7px}

       ul#info li h3 span {color:#3b3b3b;margin-right:2px}
       ul#info li h3 img {margin-right:31px;float:right}
       ul#info li p {width:100%;margin-top:25px;float:left;font-size:18px;color:#848484;line-height:24px;letter-spacing:-0.8px}

       ul#info li p.all{}
       ul#info li p.all:hover{color:#000000;}

       ul#info li p.descrip {margin-top:13px;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;text-align:justify}
```

I want to change the color of the text to black [both p] when the user hover the li
i.e. when an user moves a mouse anywhere on the list then both p tag color should change to black

I have tried the followings

```
  1) ul#info li:hover {color:black!important;}

  2) ul#info li p:hover {color:black!important;}
        In this case the text color changes to black but the problem is only one P tag color changes to black. I want both p tag color to change

  3) Tried using DIV tag inside li tag
       <ul id="info">
        <li>
          <div id="black"
            <h3><span>Text1</span>Text2
                <img src="path" alt="" />
            </h3>
            <p> DATA1 </p>
            <p class="descrip"> DATA2 </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    and #black:hover{color:black!important;}
    but doesn't work
```

**When USER moves mouse on the LI tag both P tag color should be Black**
tried many more things but can't find what is going wrong ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this :

```
 ul#info li:hover p {
     color:#000000;
 }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/r42ud/)**